# Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error `Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined` and can't find a solution to fix it.

```
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <?php
    $external_scripts = get_field('external_scripts_header', 'option');

    if (!empty($external_scripts)) {
        echo $external_scripts;
    }
    ?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.8/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
</head>    

var data;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo $tab['failas']; ?>",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response)
        {
        data = $.csv.toArrays(response);
        generateHtmlTable(data);
        }
      });
```

I have jQuery-csv.js included in header. After I get csv file I just display it into div.

Comment: please show us where and how you included jQuery-csv.js

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.8.8/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
</head> Just before head closes

Comment: please update your answer with the relevant code - your include of `jQuery-csv.js` and of your `ajax` and of your `index.html`

Comment: Well, it says the csv plugin isn't loaded when you're trying to use it. So either you're calling this script before the plugin is loaded or your page has two copies of jQuery.

Comment: I might be calling jQuery two times, because without calling it second time it says that jQuery is not defined... Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined